# Is it good practice to define an extern variable for future 'unset' variables?

Tags: c++, extern

I am looking at some code sample. In a .h file, there is this declaration:

> extern int NODATA;

which is used in many other files for variables that do not have a logical value.

Is it necessary to define it somewhere else or is it OK to leave it undefined?

Comment: It can't be used if it's not defined. Are you sure it's not defined in the corresponding `.cpp` file?

Comment: It is ok to let it undefined, if you don't want to use it. But this makes the code less readable and misleading.

Comment: @AlexFarber If he leaves it undefined, he cannot use it.  And if he doesn't use it, there's no point in declaring it.

Comment: @sftrabbit It doesn't have to be defined in the C++ source code. For instance, it could be in an assembly or library file.

Comment: @James Kanze - this is exactly what is written in my post :)

Answer (score 0):

How is it used?  If it is used by value, then it must be defined
somewhere, and it will take on the value it was given in the
initializer—by default, 0.  (And of course, it should be
const.)  If it is only used by address (i.e. `&NODATA`), then it
still needs to be defined somewhere.  But in that case, the
idiomatic convention is to use a null pointer: `NULL` (or `0`,
or if you've got C++11, `nullptr`),  There's no reason to do
otherwise, and you don't have to define anything else, either.

Answer (score 0):

It might be **technically** allowable for it not to be defined anywhere depending on what you mean by "used", but I certainly would not call it good practice. Take, for example, the following (hackish) program. Note that it uses new C++11 features, but some of the uses of `NODATA` also apply to c++03.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

extern int NODATA;

auto size = sizeof(NODATA);
auto align = alignof(NODATA);

void f(int c = NODATA)
{
    cout << "c=" << c << endl;
}

decltype(NODATA) main()
{
    cout << "size=" << size << endl;
    cout << "align=" << align << endl;

    f(0);

    // above here should all work, below may not depending on 
    // implementation and its optimization settings

    if(false && NODATA)
    {
        cout << "false && NODATA" << endl;
    }
    else if(true || NODATA)
    {
        cout << "true || NODATA" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        int i = NODATA;
    }

    // this would definitely cause a linker error
    // f();
    // but this may not
    false ? f() : f(1);

    f((NODATA-NODATA) + 2);
    f((NODATA/NODATA) + 2);
    f((4*NODATA)/NODATA);

    int arry[3] = { [0] = 1, [1] = NODATA, [1] = 2 };

    struct {
        int first;
        int second;
        int third;
    } strct = {.first = 1, .second = NODATA, .second = 2};

    return NODATA^NODATA;

    int i = NODATA;
}
```

Though some of these constructs will work despite the fact that `NODATA` is not defined anywhere (see http://ideone.com/hyjOxR for an example run), I struggle to think of any reason to actually use them.

Based on your description, however, it sounds like the rest of the files are using `NODATA` to initiliaze and/or test against other variables (presumably that can't all be optimized out):

```
#include "NODATA.h"

int aVariableThatIsActuallyUsed = NODATA;

void SomeInitFunc(void)
{
    aVariableThatIsActuallyUsed = 42;
}

int SomeOtherFunc(void)
{
    if(NODATA == aVariableThatIsActuallyUsed)
    {
        throw SomeException();
    }

    aVariableThatIsActuallyUsed--;

    return aVariableThatIsActuallyUsed;
}
```

If so, then `NODATA` has to be defined, whether in a C++ source file, an assembly file, a library, or somewhere else. Do you know for a fact that the program compiles and runs without error?